# Interpolation theorem on$(0,2 \pi)$. Suppose $f \in L^2$ , the distribution derivative $f'' \in L^2$ ,then can we show that $f' \in L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Interpolation theorem on $(0,2 \pi)$. Suppose $f \in L^2$ , the distribution derivative $f'' \in L^2$ ,then can we show that $f' \in L^2$  ?

Set $f(x)=\sum a_n e^{inx}$ and $ f''(x)=\sum b_n e^{inx}$ , then we have
$$f''(x)=\lim_N \sum_{-N}^N -in^2 a_n e^{inx}$$
in the sense of distribution , so it suffice to show $b_n = -in^2 a_n$ . However , $e^{inx} \notin C_c^{\infty}(0,2 \pi)$ so we can not use it as a test function . And I can not imagine what does the Fourier series of such functions look like .

Comment: Maybe try arguing that $f'$ is a bounded functional on $C_c$,then since $C_c$ is dense in $L^2$ you can extend $f'$ to a bounded functional on all of $L^2$ and then by Riesz it can be represented as a vector in $L^2$.

Comment: @Neal  Suppose $\phi=\sum b_n e^{inx} \in C_c$ then $<f',\phi>=\lim_N \sum_{-N}^N in^2 a_n \frac{b_n}{n}$ . Since $\sum \frac{b_n}{n} e^{inx}$ might not belongs to $C_c$ in general , I can not deduce the $L^2$ boundedness from it.

Comment: Is it possible to use the following?
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x) \overline{f'(x)} \, dx = \left[f'(x) \overline{f(x)}\right]_0^{2\pi} - \int_0^{2\pi} f''(x) \overline{f(x)} \, dx
$$

Comment: @md2perpe To ensure that LSH of the equation make sense , we need to show $f' \in L^2$ first .

Comment: @gdj. Not that $f' \in L^2.$ Only that $f'$ is Lebesgue measurable. If $f'$ is Lebesgue measurable, and integration by parts is allowed, and the RHS is finite (the integral clearly is, but how do we treat the $[\cdots]$ term?), then $f' \in L^2.$

Comment: @md2perpe  I didn't see why $f'$ is measurable . I can only show that $f'$ can be realized as an element in $C^{\infty}$ , i.e.  a sequence $\{ a_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ .

Comment: I didn't mean that $f'$ is Lebesgue measurable. What I meant is that we only need that $f'$ is Lebesgue measurable to make sense of the LHS; we don't need that LHS is finite.

Comment: Consider the function given by $$g(x) = \int_0^x f''(t)\,dt\,.$$ This is an absolutely continuous function, with $g' = f''$ (almost everywhere, and, even more important, in the sense of distributions). Hence $f' - g$ is a constant. Thus $f'$ is an absolutely continuous function.

Comment: In particular, @Daniel Fischer's comment shows that you don't even have to assume $f\in L^2$, the same conclusions holds if $f$ is only a distribution (so it's not really an interpolation result).

Answer (score 1):

Let $\chi_{\epsilon}$ be mollifiers, it’s easy to see that $\chi_{\epsilon} * f$ (resp. $\chi_{\epsilon} * f’’=(\chi_{\epsilon} * f)’’$) is a smooth function with $L^2$-norm bounded by a constant times that of $f$ (resp. that of $f’’$), and that converges in $L^2$ to $f$ (resp. $f’’$).

But if $g$ is any smooth function on the circle, then $\int_a^b{g’\overline{g’}}=[\overline{g}g’]_a^b-\int_a^b{\overline{g}g’’}$ (as suggested by md2perpe’s comment), thus $\|g’\|_2^2 \leq \|g\|_2 \|g’’\|_2$. It follows that $\chi_{\epsilon} * f’=(\chi_{\epsilon}*f)’$ is Cauchy in $L^2$ and thus converges to a $L^2$ function $g$, but also converges to $f’$ in distribution. Therefore, $g=f’$ is $L^2$.

Comment: There's a piece missing here. We need to handle that the convolutions might have support outside of $(0,2\pi)$. We also need to make sure that $\bar g g'$ is periodic so that $[\bar g g']_a^b$ vanishes. Both of these are solved, I think, if we use the periodic extension of $f$ in the convolutions and then restrict the result of the convolutions to $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: I thought that with the Fourier expansions in the OP it was implicit that we were in a periodic setting...

Comment: To me it wasn't obvious. I thought that we were only working inside $(0, 2\pi).$ Anyway, I think that it is clear now that the domain is $S^1$ parameterized by angle.